# Gradle: moving to multi project structure - cannot resolve repository

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, artifactory, gradlew

I have a project that depends on local artifactory for several dependencies.

Gradle build on this project works fine, with proper settings for repository:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${artifactoryUrl}/libs-release"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.4.10'
   }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "${artifactoryUrl}/repo"
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactoryUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-snapshot-local' // The Artifactory repository key to publish to
            username = "${artifactoryUser}" // The publisher user name
            password = "${artifactoryPassword}" // The publisher password
        }
        defaults {
            // Reference to Gradle publications defined in the build script.
            // This is how we tell the Artifactory Plugin which artifacts should be
            // published to Artifactory.
            publications('mavenJava')
            publishArtifacts = true
            // Properties to be attached to the published artifacts.
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team' : 'core']
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repoKey = 'repo'
    }
}
```

I followed gradle tutorials on multi-project structure. It looks like I can move the "repository" section to the root `gradle.build` file. However, when I run gradle build I'm getting and error on all dependencies from artifactory:

> Cannot resolve external dependency

Note: I also added the `gradle.properties` file in the root dir, which contains all the variables (artifactoryUrl etc).

So it seems that the subproject is not able to "see" the repository defined in the root `gradle.build` file. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

My `build.gradle` on the root dir looks like this now:

```
allprojects {
}

subprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "${artifactoryUrl}/libs-release"
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.4.10'
       }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${artifactoryUrl}/repo"
        }
    }

    artifactory {
        contextUrl = "${artifactoryUrl}"
        publish {
            repository {
                repoKey = 'libs-snapshot-local' // The Artifactory repository key to publish to
                username = "${artifactoryUser}" // The publisher user name
                password = "${artifactoryPassword}" // The publisher password
            }
            defaults {
                // Reference to Gradle publications defined in the build script.
                // This is how we tell the Artifactory Plugin which artifacts should be
                // published to Artifactory.
                publications('mavenJava')
                publishArtifacts = true
                // Properties to be attached to the published artifacts.
                properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team' : 'core']
            }
        }
        resolve {
            repoKey = 'repo'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you get with running with the `-i` or `-d` flags? There should be a lead there somewhere.

Comment: Only related message I see with `id` is "No local repository in Settings file defined. Using default path: /home/elad/.m2/repository"

Comment: I think you're missing the `apply plugin:`, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `repository` (and `artifactory`) block(s) in a `subprojects` or `allprojects` block. As such:

```
subprojects {
  repositories {
    maven {
        url "${artifactoryUrl}/repo"
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

This will ensure that the configuration is pushed down by the root `build.gradle` into the configuration of every of your subprojects.

Also for artifactory, don't forget to apply the artifactory plugin to all subprojects:

```
subprojects {
  apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

  ...
}
```

Comment: I did. Updated the question with the full root build.gradle file. Please review.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking at some example, I realized that the `buildscript` section should be outside the `subprojects` section, and not inside. And that `apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'` should be added inside the subprojects section as well.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${artifactoryUrl}/libs-release"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.4.10'
   }
}

subprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${artifactoryUrl}/repo"
        }
    }

    artifactory {
        contextUrl = "${artifactoryUrl}"
        publish {
            repository {
                repoKey = 'libs-snapshot-local' // The Artifactory repository key to publish to
                username = "${artifactoryUser}" // The publisher user name
                password = "${artifactoryPassword}" // The publisher password
            }
        defaults {
                // Reference to Gradle publications defined in the build script.
                // This is how we tell the Artifactory Plugin which artifacts should be
                // published to Artifactory.
                publications('mavenJava')
                publishArtifacts = true
                // Properties to be attached to the published artifacts.
                properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team' : 'core']
            }
        }
        resolve {
            repoKey = 'repo'
        }
    }
}
```